# "Throw you with a stone" vs "Throw a stone at you"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, at-with

In South African English a common mistake is to say:
"I will throw you with a stone"
where the correct phrase is:
"I will throw a stone at you".
Why is the first sentence wrong when one can say:
"I will cut you with a knife"?
Both are "I will" -action- "you with" -object-.

Possible reason: the object is distanced from you in the first case and "with" indicates grouping. Once you have thrown a stone it is separate from you but the knife stays in your hand ("with" you).

See [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=throw%20with%2C%20throw%20at&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrow%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrow%20at%3B%2Cc0) for usage of the phrases.

Comment: How common is it for people to say  "I will throw you with a stone" or similar in South Africa, and is it said by people with fluent English? Perhaps it is not a mistake but a difference between S.A. English and British English.

Comment: I would say it's common enough to be accepted in colloquial speech but probably mostly with people who do not speak English as a first language. About 10% of people speak it as a first language and a lot more can speak English as an additional language.
It is definitely a mistake. SA English follows the British rules (although there has been influence on informal writing/speaking by the US media)

Comment: You can "hit/strike you with a stone" or "bombard, pelt, shower" with a stone, or even "stone you with a stone (what else?)" But you throw a person with... a very large catapult?

Comment: @bdsl The error is made by [Afrikaans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afrikaans) speakers who translate the threat *"ek sal jou met a klip gooi"* into English word-for-word,

Comment: *Throw* has a variety of meanings. A difficult question on an exam can *throw* a student. If a stone is used in a deceptive way, it’s possible to “throw someone with a stone”.   Games played with stones include curling and go, both of which allow one player to deceive the other as to the long-term intent of a move.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is in the meaning implied by *with*.

**[With](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/with)**:

> 1.Accompanied by (another person or thing)

Ex: a nice steak with a bottle of red wine

> 2.Indicating the instrument used to perform an action:

Ex: cut the fish with a knife

When you say, *I will throw you with a stone*, the implication is throwing someone along with a stone(refer the first definition). On the other hand, when you say, *I will cut you with a knife* you mean that you will cut the person using the weapon of your choice, which in this case, is a knife(second definition).

The *I will...you with* was a good observation, though.

Comment: Thanks! Number 2 is what I was looking for. In Afrikaans "with" (met) is used more loosely than "with" and that is probably where the "with" was influenced from.

Comment: I will *hit* you with a stone might work though.

Comment: @Cronax to me the only difference is that you *throw* the stone, you don't *hit* it.

Comment: @PierreArlaud But you *wield* the knife, you don't *cut* it ;)

Comment: @anotherdave which is why this is an interesting question. But when you say "I will throw you with a stone", it's not you I throw, on the contrary to "I will cut you with a knife", in which case I would indeed be cutting you

Answer (score 12):

This is the story for standard British and American Englishes:

The Direct Objects of different verbs represent different entities in relation to the story told by the verb. The Direct Object of the verb *CUT* often indicates the thing being incised. Here is a picture of someone "cutting a cake":

[image]

The Direct Object of the verb *throw* usually represents the thing travelling through the air. Here is a picture of someone "throwing a cake":

[image]

Notice that the Direct Object of *throw* doesn't represent the person getting a cake when there is only one Object of the verb. Here is a picture of someone "throwing a person":

[image]

This is the prime reason why *I'm going to throw you* does not achieve the meaning required for most speakers of British and American Englishes. The story may be different for speakers of other types of English.

---

**Grammar note:**

Of course when used with *two* objects, the Indirect Object represents the recipient of the missile, and the Direct Object is the missile itself. However, with this usage, the idea conveyed is usually that the person receiving the missile co-operates in receiving it:

- He threw [me] [the keys].

---

<sub>**Picture references**</sub>

<sub>1. [Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Cut-a-Cake-with-Fishing-Wire).</sub> 
 <sub>2. [Pandamari](http://pandamari.deviantart.com/) at [Cabin Pressure Fans](http://www.cabinpressurefans.co.uk/fan-art/).</sub> 
 <sub>3. [Mansitioning.com](http://www.mansitioning.com/2015/01/functiond-s-id-var-js-fjs-d.html).</sub>

Comment: Is this not because you are effectively saying *He threw [to] me the keys* - *me* being the indirect object requiring prepositional connection to the verb? Elision is less likely for IOs which follow the DO.

Comment: @WS2 That's the traditional story - for Indirect Objects, yes :)

Comment: +1 for the picture of someone throwing a person. (also, good explanation)

Comment: @WS2: AFAIK, historically, the "me" in "throw me the keys" used to be in the [dative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_case), back when English still had such case distinctions. (Compare e.g. German "_wirf **mir** die Schlüssel_".) The cases got merged together, but the "<verb> <recipient> <direct object>" construction survived for some verbs ("give", "tell", "send", etc.), generally describing a transfer of something, with word order instead of case now serving to distinguish the two objects. So it's not so much an elided preposition as a loss of case markers.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen But if you place the IO after the DO the preposition returns. *He threw the keys to me*.

Comment: @WS2: Sure, because you've broken the "<verb> <ind.obj.> <dir.obj.>" pattern by moving the direct object immediately after the verb, and there are no longer any visible case markers in English to let you vary the order of the objects, so you have to specify the recipient some other way -- and pretty much the only other way is to indicate the recipient using an adverbial phrase like "to me", which can go anywhere. My point is that, while "throw to me the keys" would indeed also be valid, it isn't and never was idiomatic, and it's not the historical form that "throw me the keys" evolved from.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thank you for the much-needed illumination.

Answer (score 5):

It all hangs on the meaning of ***to throw***. It looks as though ***to throw*** can mean ***to hit*** in South Africa. You definitely can hit someone with a stone. But this is not a meaning you will find in dictionaries. The basic, conventional meaning of ***to throw*** is, quoting from [Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/throw_1):

> **1** Throw a ball/stone etc. [intransitive and transitive] to make an object such as a ball move quickly through the air by pushing your hand forward quickly and letting the object go

So, if you want to hit someone with a stone, you usually send a stone, not the person, flying through the air. If you’re on ship I suppose you could ***throw*** somebody overboard ***with a stone*** tied to them to make sure they sink. Or you could ***throw*** somebody off a horse ***with a stone***, i. e., by hitting them with a stone.

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the difference between transitive and intransitive verbs. I think.

Transitive verbs require an object, whilst intransitive ones do not.

With transitive verbs, the first object, or whatever stands for an object (most often a noun or a personal pronoun), after the verb is most likely the object.

In "I'll throw you with a stone" the word "you" immediately follows "throw"; this means that "you" is the object of "throw"; which would imply that the speaker will hurl the interlocutor, after which said interlocutor, propelled by the force of the speaker's powerful throw, will have to travel some distance involuntarily, presumably through the air, and crash-land once the gravity and friction have worn down the initial force imparted to him or her by the act of throwing. The stone, then, serves as an instrument: the speaker intends to toss the interlocutor some distance with the help of that stone (possibly sling-shaped), in accordance with the prophecy.

Oh, and, by the way, despite the Biblical allusion, throwing rocks is more common than throwing stones these days. Hmm. That's not exactly accurate. Wait. Ah! I got it: stones are cast; rocks are thrown. Or hurled.

Comment: This makes sense!

Comment: Except that in the English of England a *rock* is something usually too heavy to lift. We go *rock-climbing*.

Comment: @WS2: Oh, come on! Tell the truth: "English rocks are so heavy, and we English so well-mannered, we never throw them at anyone other than the French."

Answer (score 1):

Conversely you'd need to come up with a very convoluted sentence to include "cut at you with a knife". Also "throw X *at* someone" is very different to "throw X *to* someone". Some verbs need a preposition in some sentences to make the meaning clear. It's the verb rather than the noun (weapon here) that makes the difference: you could "hurt someone with" a knife or a stone or other projectile.

Answer (score 1):

"He threw me with a stone" is a very similar construction to "He presented me with a medal", and the alternative "He threw a stone at me" is a very similar construction to "He presented a medal to me".  In both constructions, we have two complements to a verb whose relationship to the verb is expressed by prepositions.  But it's hard to see what is going on, because the preposition that happens to come next to the verb is lost.

That is, abstractly, we must begin with

> He threw at me with a stone
>    He presented to me with a medal

and allow for the two complements to occur in either order after the verb.  Whichever oblique complement turns up next to the verb gets promoted to direct object.

Although Fillmore did not deal with these specific examples, the fundamental idea of this analysis is that behind Charles Fillmore's theory of Case Grammar.  At a deep level, the relationship of the verb of a clause to its complements is expressed by prepositions in English and by various oblique cases in many other languages, then certain of these oblique complements are promoted to become the non-oblique "upright" subject or object, or nominative and accusative.

Answer (score -1):

I personally think that throwing a stone at someone has a varied and passive meaning. You can throw a stone at someone to grab their attention. On the other hand, when you throw someone with something, you do it with the intention of hurting them. A listener will be able to distinguish between the nature of the following sentences when the speaker says:

> 1. He threw the ball at me.
> 2. He threw me with a ball.

We can gather from the first sentence that this was probably a game. There were several targets and they happened to strike you out so now you are it.
The second sentence insinuates/could mean that their actions were a violent one.